# How to zip values with types? Shapeless

Tags: scala, shapeless

I have a `HList` of coproducts that looks like this:

```scala
(A :+: B :+: CNil) :: (Foo :+: Bar :+: CNil) :: HNil
```

This `HList` *will* be a value in my program. E.g.,:

```scala
val myhlist: (A :+: B :+: CNil) :: (Foo :+: Bar :+: CNil) :: HNil = ???
```

I have another HList of coproducts, that looks like this:

```scala
(A :+: CNil) :: (Bar :+: CNil) :: HNil
```

However, this HList will *not* be a value throughout the program; it only exists in the type level.

I want to zip these two HLists with this zipping function:

```scala
def zipFn[A <: Coproduct, B <: Coproduct](a: A)(implicit basis: Basis[A, B]) = {
  a.deembed[B]
}
```

`A` is an element from the former HList (which will have values throughout the program), and `B` is an element from the latter HList. I want to zip values (`A`s) with types (`B`s).

Might be a very simple question but somehow I am troubled with this?

Any pointers?

--

My current idea was to use a curried polymorphic function in Shapeless; something like:

```scala
object myZipFn extends Poly1 {
  implicit def default[A <: Coproduct, B <: Coproduct](implicit basis: Basis[A, B]) = at[A] { a => a.deembed[B] }
}

val curried = Poly.curried(myZipFn)
```

but doesn't make much sense since `default` asks for A and B at the same time.

My idea would be to take in `B` (the type with no value) generically first, then return a new function that asks for `A` as a value, and then we have both.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.zipWith` accepts `Poly2`, not `Poly1`. So `myZipFn` should be

```scala
object myZipFn extends Poly2 {
  implicit def default[A <: Coproduct, B <: Coproduct](implicit
    basis: Basis[A, B]
  ): Case.Aux[A, B, basis.Out] = at[A, B] { (a, _) => a.deembed[B] }
}
```

At the not necessary 2nd argument of `.zipWith` (because you have the 2nd HList only on type level, not on value level) you can substitute an HList of nulls (but typed properly)

```scala
val myhlist: (A :+: B :+: CNil) :: (Foo :+: Bar :+: CNil) :: HNil = ???
type hlist1 = (A :+: CNil) :: (Bar :+: CNil) :: HNil

object nullPoly extends Poly0 {
  implicit def default[A]: Case0[A] = at(null.asInstanceOf[A])
}

val nullHlist: hlist1 = FillWith[nullPoly.type, hlist1].apply()

myhlist.zipWith(nullHlist)(myZipFn)
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to have an HList of nulls, you'll have to define custom `Zip`/`ZipWith` type class for value/type-level 1st argument and type-level 2nd argument.

Other use cases of `FillWith`/`nullPoly` trick:

[How to obtain all possible members of a coproduct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66672681/how-to-obtain-all-possible-members-of-a-coproduct/)

[Scala - looping over case class names to use as type parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69598705/scala-looping-over-case-class-names-to-use-as-type-parameters)

[How to get field names and field types from a Generic Type in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63298926/how-to-get-field-names-and-field-types-from-a-generic-type-in-scala)

[Is it possible to have a variable type list in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57478837/is-it-possible-to-have-a-variable-type-list-in-scala)

[Get case class field's name and type with shapeless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55504430/get-case-class-fields-name-and-type-with-shapeless)

[How to pass into generic type using a Symbol or Type object into a generic typed function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63405194/how-to-pass-into-generic-type-using-a-symbol-or-type-object-into-a-generic-typed)

Comment: Smart, smart. Many thanks!